# How can I create complex unique using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have to make a field that contains a http link to be unique in a Rails model. In addition to that, I would like to reject link variations as well like:

- If I try to insert an http**S** address when an http address exist
- If I try to insert a link with parameters when there is another link without parameters or different ones

I have found this link that may indicate the answer of my problem but I hope that I can do this directly in the index as my case doesn't change as time passes.

[In Rails, How do I validates_uniqueness_of :field with a scope of last 6 months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966699/in-rails-how-do-i-validates-uniqueness-of-field-with-a-scope-of-last-6-months)

There is no need to provide the exact answer as I have some experience with regular expression. A different example or a reference already would be wonderful as I couln't find none

Comment: You might want to consider creating a Link model, having attributes like "protocol" (http/https), "port" (80/43), "url", "params" and then validates the uniqueness of the url (which excludes the params & the protocol as you wanted)

Comment: @MrYoshiji, it seems interesting. Don't you want to create an answer for that?

Comment: Just did, it's not complete but gives you a base for the Link Model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this can give you the first steps:

```
require 'uri'

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :link

  validate :check_link_integrity
  validates :url, uniqueness: true
  before_save :parse_link

  def check_link_integrity
    begin
      URI::parse(self[:link])
      return true
    rescue URI::InvalidURIError => e
      return false
    end
  end

  def parse_link
    uri_link = URI::parse( self.attributes.delete(:link) )
    self.url = uri_link.host + uri_link.path
    self.protocol = uri_link.scheme
    self.parameters = uri_link.query
  end

  def to_s
    "#{protocol}://#{url}?#{parameters}"
  end

end
```

URI module documentation: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html

Comment: Sorry for the delay... I was solving other issues in my app... I tried it in the last couple of days and started to work replacing "self.attributes.delete(:link)" with "self.link" but the edit view don't show the current link. Am I doing something wrong? Any resource that solves a similar issue would help as I couldn't find any. Thanks!

Comment: I had an idea today that seems working although it may not the best solution. I cut the before_save, included a param in parse_link, used it link "uri_link = URI::parse(param_link", called it in the controller passing params[:link][:link] as the parameter, and renaming to_s to link

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with a custom validation method using an URI module

All you need is 
uri = URI(your_url)
and then basically check if there is another record with the same uri.host and uri.path.

Yes, this is not a rails way and this will require calculations on each validation, however your request is not simple as well.

Another way would be to store only hostname + path in the database (meaning: to cut protocol and parameters from url during saving). This way you can use built-in uniqness check mechanism

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know URI. I think cutting is dangerous. But maybe you don't mean losing this information.